# Android preserve variable state during minimize and re launch

Tags: android

i have a simple activity where i start a service in onCreate depending on checkbox state.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(savedInstanceState == null)
        Log.e(TAG,"savedInstanceState is null");
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        Log.e(TAG,"savedInstanceState is not null");
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

on checkbox state checked starting the service and setting `serviceStarted`

```
toggleButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {



        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(isChecked){

                Log.e(TAG,"starting service");
                serviceStarted = true;
                startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));

            }else{

                serviceStarted = false;
                stopService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class));


            }

        }
    });
```

i have overrided below functions

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e(TAG,"onSaveInstanceState called");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    Log.e(TAG,"onResume called : serviceStarted = "+String.valueOf(serviceStarted));
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(TAG,"onPause called : serviceStarted = "+String.valueOf(serviceStarted));
}
```

Now in my logcat, on minimize and re-launching the app after starting service, i see below

```
04-22 12:34:42.150: E/MainActivity(19720): onPause called : serviceStarted = true
04-22 12:34:44.700: E/MainActivity(19720): onResume called : serviceStarted = false
```

---

Now my need is

I want to preserve state of `serviceStarted` **without using** `sharedpreferences`

Anyway there, or should i go with service binding model ? Please help Thank you

Comment: that's what `onSaveInstanceState` is for...

Answer (score 2):

Well, just use the whole save instance state thing, that's what it's for:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBoolean("serviceStarted", mServiceStarted);
}

protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle state) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    mServiceStarted = state.getBoolean("serviceStarted", false);
}
```

But actually, if your activity gets destroyed for reals (by back button or by the OS), you'll still lose state, so the more reliable option is to use `SharedPreferences`.

**But** in your case, service can still get killed between the times your activity pauses and gets brought back -- then your serviceStarted will be obsolete. So just use a static member to know the state:

```
public MyService extends Service {
    private static volatile boolean mIsRunning = false;
    public void onCreate() {
        MyService.mIsRunning = true;
    }
    public void onDestroy() {
        MyService.mIsRunning = false;
    }
    public static boolean isRunning() {
        return mIsRunning;
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me try your 2nd approach!

Comment: Ivan, why `mIsRunning` should be volatile ?

Comment: It's a thread safety thing. `volatile` ensures no value caching occurs when it's accessed by different threads i.e. all threads will have the same value for it at all times. You need that because the variable is going to be accessed by the thread that runs the service an the UI thread that's going to initialize your checkbox state. And possibly, any other thread you might use in the future that will want to know whether the service is running.